# Is there any course available online on designing ui automation framework using Selenium and Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-design, testng, uiautomation

Is there any good course available online that explains designing UI automation framework using Selenium and Java, integrating logging, reporting, etc. ?
Maybe also talk about some best practices.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to make your own framework, that is fine, but I would start with something like Selenide, so that your end result is much simplified.

Answer (score -1):

There is **"Automation framework development with Selenium C# (Advanced)"** on Udemy that I found very useful. I know it is C# and not Java, but it is pretty easy to follow along. It is great at explaining and showing practical examples of refactoring test code and making the framework as maintainable and expandable as possible.

There are some good free courses on [Test Automation University](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/):

- **"From Scripting to Framework with Selenium and C#"** (C# again, sorry, but if you know Java or other Object Oriented languages you should be fine).
- Another one, this time in Java is **"Selenium WebDriver with Java"**. It is not so focused on framework development but it is excellent for Selenium and Java in general and there are many things to pick up for general use so it's useful for frameworks as well.